# /bin/sh: VARIABLE: command not found

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following target, in my Makefile:

```
~/.zshrc: zsh/*
    DESTDIR ?= $(shell echo '~/.') 
    SUDO ?= $(shell echo '') 
    sed -e "s_DESTDIR_$(DESTDIR)_" \
        -e "s_SUDO_$(SUDO)_" \
        -e "s_LIBDIR_$(LIBDIR)_" \
        -e '/^#/ d' $+ > $@
```

But whenever I run `make ~.zshrc` I get the following error:

```
DESTDIR ?= ~/. 
/bin/sh: DESTDIR: command not found
make: *** [/Users/henrikgiesel/.zshrc] Error 127
```

I have no clue what causes this. Do I have to escape something? I have `PWD ?= $(shell pwd)` at another point in the file and it works just fine.

Comment: You can't declare variables inside recipes like this.

Comment: Note that `make` uses `/bin/sh` and that is not a link to `zsh`, it would seem.  The spaces around the assignments aren't valid in regular `/bin/sh`; the `?=` isn't valid `sh` syntax either.  And you'd have to use semicolons and backslashes to ensure that what's set in line one of the command sequence is available in line 3 and beyond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inside of `target: respondencies`-block is not the same as file level of the Makefile.

Commands like `DESTDIR ?= $(shell echo '~/.')` can only be executed on file level.
Everything inside a `target`-block is basically a shell-command, executed by /bin/sh.